# App crashed but logCat still running

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

Does anyone know why the logCat keeps on running even though the app is crashed ?

```
11-27 13:00:37.521    5893-5893/? I/dumpstate﹕ done
11-27 13:00:37.526    6064-6064/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-27 13:00:37.541    6055-6055/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 192 unimplemented (abstract) methods
11-27 13:00:37.551    5992-5992/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-27 13:00:37.556    5992-6029/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 13% free 717K/820K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 3ms
11-27 13:00:37.596    6078-6078/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-27 13:00:37.596    6078-6078/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-27 13:00:37.601   2663-20947/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
11-27 13:00:37.601    2663-2663/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ handleKeyguardVisibilityChanged(1)
11-27 13:00:37.601    6055-6055/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-27 13:00:37.621   2663-15938/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
11-27 13:00:37.621    2663-2663/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ handleKeyguardVisibilityChanged(1)
11-27 13:00:37.626    6078-6078/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 192 unimplemented (abstract) methods
11-27 13:00:37.671    5979-5979/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-27 13:00:37.671    5979-6045/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 13% free 717K/820K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 3ms
11-27 13:00:37.686    6078-6078/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-27 13:00:37.691    6114-6114/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-27 13:00:37.691    6114-6114/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-27 13:00:37.716    6114-6114/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 192 unimplemented (abstract) methods
11-27 13:00:37.751    6018-6018/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-27 13:00:37.751    6018-6066/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 13% free 717K/820K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 2ms
11-27 13:00:37.776    6114-6114/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
11-27 13:00:37.791    6010-6010/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
```

These are the red color words show in logCat

```
11-27 13:01:36.301    2663-2663/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager﹕ ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
11-27 13:01:36.296    2663-2663/? E/KeyguardHostView﹕ KeyguardHostView()
11-27 13:04:34.966    2441-2762/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 5375
11-27 13:07:46.711    6556-6556/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module     (No such file or directory)
11-27 13:07:46.711    6556-6556/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
```

Comment: Dear downvoters, please give me a solution or explain why downvotes my question

Comment: Make sure you have selected your application from drop down at the top of the Android Monitor tab. If there's 'No Debuggable Application' then it will show logs of entire os.

Comment: If you want logcat only for your app, then add package name in filter, then you will be able to see only logcat of your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **matthewrdev** logcat give report of all things which is happening in your android device.

If you want logcat only for your appication, then add package name in filter, then you will be able to see only logcat of your application.

**Add filter in Eclipse  :**

1. Open your logcat
2. Click on green "+" button
3. Then below dialog will display.
4. Add your application package name.

[image]

Now you will be able to see logcat only of your application.

Answer (score 2):

Logcat is **system** wide, it reports on everything that's happening inside Android. This allows you to diagnose external factors that may have affected your application (and events that occurred before and after it ran)

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html):

> The Android logging system provides a mechanism for collecting and viewing **system** debug output. Logs from various applications and portions of the system are collected in a series of circular buffers, which then can be viewed and filtered by the logcat command. You can use logcat from an ADB shell to view the log messages.